# PHP get next days of the week depending on current day of the week

Tags: php, date, dayofweek

I must to fill my chart with visitors number, but, when displaying current week data i got the next days value to 0.

EG: today is Monday so I get 2016-06-20 as column value, but next column value name is 0 cause I haven't data for the next days.

The chart index must to be like this:

```
|| 20 Jun 2016 || 21 Jun 2016 || 22 Jun 2016 || 23 Jun 2016 || etc.
```

And now I got this:

```
|| 20 Jun 2016 || 1 Jan 1970 || 1 Jan 1970 || 1 Jan 1970 || etc.
```

So I've tried to populate the missing days using this function:

```
function get_day($count) {
    if ($count == NULL) {
        $dweek = date("w");
        for ($i = 1; $i <= 6; $i++) {
            echo $i;
            switch ($i) {
                case 1:
                    $day = $dweek+1;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $day = $dweek+2;
                    break;
                case 3:
                    $day = $dweek+3;
                    break;
                case 4:
                    $day = $dweek+4;
                    break;
                case 5:
                    $day = $dweek+5;
                    break;
                case 6:
                    $day = $dweek+6;
                    break;
            }
        }
        $current = date("d M Y",strtotime("+$day day"));
    } else {
        $current = date("d M Y",strtotime($count));
    }
    return $current;
}
```

But using this now I got:

```
|| 20 Jun 2016 || 27 Jun 2016 || 27 Jun 2016 || 27 Jun 2016 || etc.
```

So I'm missing something, but after 2 hours I can't see how to do.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: Returning inside the `switch()` is bad idea, and a function can only return one value once.

Comment: So to simplify: you have a start date, and just need to generate the next six days after that start date?

Comment: Your logic is a little wrong. Please put the code you are calling and using this function. I will fix it.

Comment: @jszobody Exactly.

Comment: @Mojtaba I will call this simply passing a string to get_day() retrieved by the database.

Comment: @andreaem, I can't understand why you are returning $day. So, I need more code. You can update your question

Comment: @Mojtaba was a typo, I want to put $day in strtotime("+n day"); but using this i got only the last day in the switch (eg. 27 Jun) I've update my question.

Comment: @andreaem, you still have more unclear actions. First, you have to remove the line which returns $day. Second, Why your 'for loop' is going to 7 but, you don't have any case for that? Third, why do you use a loop. Actually, in your code, the $day is always $dweek+6 .  That's why I am asking you to put more code. Don't worry. No one steals your code.

Comment: carbon ? why you dont use carbon?

Comment: @Mojtaba 1: I've removed the return, 2: another typo, make the correction. 3: I wish to use a loop to cycle the $day++.  I'm not putting more code why I think people steal, it's why there is nothing more to paste, I'm using get_day($siteViewsThisWeek[1][1]); that send to the function a string like 2016-06-20 nothing more

Comment: It could be more slimmed. Please put your if statement line of code

Answer (score 1):

With the use of  [datetime](http://php.net/manual/de/class.datetime.php)  and [datetime.modify](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.modify.php) :

```
$res = "|| ";

for ($d = 1; $d < 8; $d++) {
    $dt = new DateTime();
    $m = $dt->modify("+$d days");
    $f = $m->format("d M Y");
    $res .= $f . " || ";
}

echo $res;
```

Comment: I'm trying to make this function get_day($count) {
 if ($count == NULL) {
  for ($d = 0; $d < 6; $d++) {
    $current = ((new DateTime())->modify("+$d days"))->format('d M Y');
  s}
 } else {
  $current = date("d M Y",strtotime($count));
 }
 return $current;
} but got an unexpected object operator (->)

Comment: I still don't understand your intention but there is a typo in your code. It should be: `function get_day($count = null)
{
if (empty($count)) {
 for ($d = 0; $d < 6; $d++) {
  $current .= ((new DateTime())->modify("+$d days"))->format('d M Y');
 }
} else {
 $current = date("d M Y",strtotime($count));
}
return $current;
}`

Comment: pasting your code return the same error: :  syntax error, unexpected '->' (T_OBJECT_OPERATOR)

Comment: Using PHP Version < 5.4.0?

Comment: I'm using 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.17

Comment: You can't do `new DateTime()->...`. This is throwing the parse error. Do it like the edited answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = '2016-06-20'; //replace this by your date
$statement = '';
for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
    $statement.= ' || ' . date('d M y', strtotime("$date +$i day"));
}
echo $statement;
```

Now, you can use your date instead of $date.

[DEMO](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d99c0c36221bf4ef9d58feab20e2a6fdd06b3bb5)

Comment: Thanks, where I must to put this part of code? what I must to put in the if statement?

Comment: @andreaem, Sorry. I had a wrong understanding. I just updated the code

Comment: Still get 26 Jun 2016.

Comment: @andreaem. You can change the number in the loop. Customize it as you want. For example, change 7 to 6.

Comment: I know, but i still get 26 Jun for all the results.

Comment: @andreaem, That's impossible. I put a DEMO. You are doing something wrong. Put the code you are using

Comment: function get_day($date) {
 if ($date == NULL) { 
  $current = '';
  for($i = 0; $i < 7; $i++){
      $current =  " " . date('d M Y', strtotime("$date +$i day"));
  }
 } else { 
  $current = date("d M Y",strtotime($date)); 
 } 
  return $current; 
}

Comment: Maybe there is an error cause i need to put these dates in a variable, every day need to be a variable so I'm call this using $v1 = get_day(); $v2 = get_day(); $v3 = get_day() etc.

Comment: here is a link to see where to put the data http://imgur.com/OzwlNFz first data element got $v21 name, second $v22, third $v23 etc

Comment: @andreaem, you need to have a date. What's your logic if there is no date? I assume you should do this: if ($date == NULL) { $date = date('Y-m-d'); .... . Put your complete code in here: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/